# Hide element if other class exist

Tags: javascript

i know how to do it with `jquery`, but how with clean `javascript`? Any help how to do this?

Here is my code

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('tagone')[0];

if(element !== null){ 
     document.getElementByClassName('classsix')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You have typo in `getElementByClassName`, missing `s`...should be `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: If you want to check if an element with a specific _class_ exists, you want `getElementByClassName` in the first line as well, and not `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: mention your jQuery Code. It will be easier to understand your Question.

Comment: Please add your jQuery code. I don't know exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hidden` [DOM attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) or create a new class called `hide` and use the logic accordingly.

```
var element = document.querySelector('tagone'); // returns only first match
if(element) { 
    document.querySelector('.classsix').setAttribute('hidden',true);
}
```

or you can create the class in css `.hide { display: none; }` and use `document.querySelector('.classsix').classList.add('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

your code is right.
you can use like this also

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('tagone')[0];
 var element1= document.getElementsByClassName('classsix')[0];
   if(element && element1){
     element.style.display = 'none';
   }
```

Comment: I test it, not working because: document.getElementByClassName is not a function

Comment: @MoreDeveloper271 it is getElement`s`ByClassName

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working.

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('tagone')[0] != null) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('classix')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function is getElement**s**ByClassName you missed **'s'**

```
function hide(){

    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
    y[0].style.display = 'none'
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link.](https://codepen.io/pzombade/pen/NoKaZW?editors=1111)